# how to fix context conversation

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to fix context problem in Android Studio?

```
public class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    MainFragment context;
    List<Note> noteList = new ArrayList<>();
}

public NotesAdapter(MainFragment context, List<Note> noteList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.noteList = noteList;
}

public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_note, parent, false);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

}
```

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sure @QuantumPete

Answer (score 0):

Using Recyclerview you dont need to pass the context throught the constructor.

You can use the ViewGroup parent and take the context from there:

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_note, parent, false);
```

So your adapter should looks like that:

```
List<Note> noteList = new ArrayList<>();

public NotesAdapter(List<Note> noteList) {
    this.noteList = noteList;
}

public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_note, parent, false);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

}
```

I hope it helps you.